# How to print random int sequence (scala)?

Tags: scala

I import scala.math._

and print random int sequence just like this form

range = (1 to 5)

print random int sequence (3, 2, 1, 4, 5).

How to do by for loop? T T

Comment: Do you want a random permutation of the range [1, 5] or five independent random numbers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import scala.util.Random
for (i <- Random.shuffle((1 to 5).toSeq)) println(i)
```